# Android FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates() returning same location coordinates

Tags: java, android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I found two types of question like this one on SO, but both have no answers.

I'm using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get the location of my device. I've lunched a background service to get the location using `requestLocationUpdates()`.

Even when the application is in foreground, the returned latitude and longitude of the methods aren't changing.

Here's a snippet of how I'm using the class:

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(new LocationRequest(), locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

`locationCallback` is just a method which will print the Longitude and Latitude on the console.

All permissions are granted and I'm checking for the permissions in my manifest. Here's the permissions I've added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".LocationService" />
</application>
```

`LocationService` is the service where I'm trying to get the location.

Anyone have an idea where's the issue?? I've been stuck for hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen for location updates if you want to have changes.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates

Or it will return all the time the same last known location if no app asks for location updates.